# Increasing Contrast of Topographic Image in R

Tags: r, geography

[image]Brand new to R, so a little foreign to me, but I Created a topographic image using Landsat, and .hgt data. I got an image out but tried to increase contrast using the scales tool. It is still giving me out a whitewashed image, and if I try to increase it form c(0,1) it gives me an error. {See both below}

What should I do to make this look better?

```
install.packages(c("rayshader", "raster", "sp"))
library(rayshader)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(scales)
---
memory.limit(size = 56000)
---
elevation1 = raster::raster("C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Desktop/N47W123.hgt")
elevation2 = raster::raster("C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Desktop/N47W124.hgt")


wash_elevation = raster::merge(elevation1,elevation2)

height_shade(raster_to_matrix(wash_elevation)) %>%
  plot_map()

------

wash_r = raster::raster("C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Desktop/LC08_L1TP_047027_20140915_20170303_01_T1_B4.TIF")
wash_g = raster::raster("C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Desktop/LC08_L1TP_047027_20140915_20170303_01_T1_B3.TIF")
wash_b = raster::raster("C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Desktop/LC08_L1TP_047027_20140915_20170303_01_T1_B2.TIF")

wash_rgb = raster::stack(wash_r, wash_g, wash_b)
raster::plotRGB(wash_rgb, scale=255^2)
---
wash_rgb_corrected = sqrt(raster::stack(wash_r, wash_g, wash_b))
raster::plotRGB(wash_rgb_corrected)
--
raster::crs(wash_r)
## CRS arguments:
##  +proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
## +towgs84=0,0,0
---
raster::crs(wash_elevation)
## CRS arguments:
##  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
---
crs(wash_r)
## CRS arguments:
##  +proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
## +towgs84=0,0,0
---
wash_elevation_utm = raster::projectRaster(wash_elevation, crs = crs(wash_r), method = "bilinear")
crs(wash_elevation_utm)
## CRS arguments:
##  +proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
## +towgs84=0,0,0
---
bottom_left = c(y=-123.704087, x=47.013711)
top_right   = c(y=-122.124594, x=47.930524)

extent_latlong = sp::SpatialPoints(rbind(bottom_left, top_right), proj4string=sp::CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
extent_utm = sp::spTransform(extent_latlong, raster::crs(wash_elevation_utm))

e = raster::extent(extent_utm)
e

---
wash_rgb_cropped = raster::crop(wash_rgb_corrected, e)
elevation_cropped = raster::crop(wash_elevation_utm, e)

names(wash_rgb_cropped) = c("r","g","b")

wash_r_cropped = rayshader::raster_to_matrix(wash_rgb_cropped$r)
wash_g_cropped = rayshader::raster_to_matrix(wash_rgb_cropped$g)
wash_b_cropped = rayshader::raster_to_matrix(wash_rgb_cropped$b)

washel_matrix = rayshader::raster_to_matrix(elevation_cropped)

wash_rgb_array = array(0,dim=c(nrow(wash_r_cropped),ncol(wash_r_cropped),3))

wash_rgb_array[,,1] = wash_r_cropped/255 #Red layer
wash_rgb_array[,,2] = wash_g_cropped/255 #Blue layer
wash_rgb_array[,,3] = wash_b_cropped/255 #Green layer

wash_rgb_array = aperm(wash_rgb_array, c(2,1,3))

plot_map(wash_rgb_array)
---

wash_rgb_contrast = scales::rescale(wash_rgb_array,to=c(0,1))

plot_map(wash_rgb_contrast)
---
plot_3d(wash_rgb_contrast, washel_matrix, windowsize = c(1100,900), zscale = 15, shadowdepth = -50,
        zoom=0.5, phi=45,theta=-45,fov=70, background = "#F2E1D0", shadowcolor = "#523E2B")
render_snapshot(title_text = "West Washington | Imagery: Landsat 8 | DEM: 30m SRTM",
                title_bar_color = "#1f5214", title_color = "white", title_bar_alpha `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `raster::stretch` function.  The only problem is that it only works on a raster object, so you either have to (1) go through the hassle of converting between an array and a raster object and then back again, or (2) just move the contrast work earlier in your code.

The `raster::stretch` function will help adjust the contrast, you just have to tell it how you want it adjusted by telling it the new minimum and maximum percentile (range of 0-1). In the example code I showed below, it's set for the 2nd percentile and the 98th percentile. Adjust as needed to get the color you want. It may take a couple of minutes to run this if it has to read the raster file from the disk.

I'll go with the easier second (2) approach. Add this after you create the `wash_rgb_cropped` object and use `wash_rgb_contrast_stretch` with the next step in the process.

```
  wash_rgb_contrast_stretch <-
  raster::stretch(wash_rgb_cropped,
    minq = .02,
    maxq = .98
  )
raster::plotRGB(wash_rgb_corrected)
```